# Excluding a child module from being executed in Maven via a command line option

Tags: maven

I have a maven project with 5 children, however when I run it, I want the last one not to be executed. I could easily commend it out from the pom file for that, however I would like to know, is there a command line option to exclude a child module from being executed?

Comment: Do you have special needs to exclude a single module ? For what purposes ?

Comment: performance, that one single project is a GWT module which takes a lot to compile.

Answer (score 10):

I have this configuration in the current project I am working on to exclude some modules.

In your pom that declares the modules, just put the list of the modules you want to run every time:

```
<modules>
    <module>this-is</module>
    <module>always-needed</module>
</modules>
```

and then, add a profile section in the same pom and move the modules you don't want to run every time:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>do-additional-module</id>
        <modules>
            <module>this-is-rarely-needed</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now when you run `mvn package`, only the modules `this-is` and `always-needed` are executed and when you specify the profile `mvn -P do-additional-module package` the reactor will run the previous modules and `this-is-rarely-needed`.

M.

Comment: This will produce problems in relationship with maven release problem, cause in case of a release you might activate one or not and so a child will not correctly updated.

Comment: This is mostly for development purpose, of course when releasing, you should do a full build.

Answer (score 1):

**You can achieve this with a [profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).**  A maven profile in the parent pom.xml can include additional child modules.

Here's an example.  Whem activated, this "*include*" profile will include a second child module.

```
<modules>
    <module>child-module-one</module>
</modules>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>include</id>
        <modules>
            <module>child-module-two</module>
        </modules>
    </profile>
</profile>
```

If you trigger a maven build phase at the parent level (compile in this example), and activate this profile - e.g.

```
mvn compile -P include
```

you will include your second child module.  If you were to avoid activating that profile, e.g. by just running:

```
mvn compile
```

then your second child module is not included.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there a any such option with current maven implementation.

You can try out one thing : create another project having only first 4 child projects. So whenever you need to build only 4 instead of 5 , use that one.

Its not necessary that you create another parent project for this. See [Aggregation for maven projects](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) for more info on that.

Comment: But the main pom file holds all the necessary project info, and copying it would mean that I will have to check for changes and update it manually all the time.

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer there is no option like this.

The best solution to avoid problems during release etc. is to use a profile but not on the level of modules better in the child module itself:

In the child module use a profile to activate/deactivate the actions needed.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
     <id>whatEver</id>
     <build>
      ...
     </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```